# About VEINS ver 4 (stable)

Tags: omnet++, veins

When will the stable VEINS ver 4 will be available tentatively and what will be its features? Will it have new features like vehicle density, security models and others? 
Thank you.

Comment: the vehicle density can be controlled via the `numVehicles` parameter in the `omnetpp.ini` file. Example: `*.manager.numVehicles = <your-wish>` . Regarding additional features, I don't think there will be any major changes

Comment: I tried with    *.manager.numVehicles = <your-wish>  along with the earlagen.rou.xml 's number=50 vehicle... what is the difference between them.   Vehicle density in my case is number of vehicle/area. The size of veins scenario is 2500mX2500m . Actually, i did not find so much difference between *.manager.numVehicles = 50 and earlagen.rou.xml's number=50. can you please put some light onthis?

Answer (score 1):

A stable version of [Veins 4 is available for download](http://veins.car2x.org/download/).

Aside from bug fixes, it offers enhanced visualization options, enhanced phy layer models, improved extensibility, and a screenshot/screencast recorder.
Note that, as the TraCI API was changed to report all angles in a different format, Veins 4.3 requires SUMO version 0.25.0.

In contrast, keeping the number of vehicles in the simulation constant (that is, using a fixed vehicle density) has been included since Veins 3 alpha 2 (see the comment by user4786271). If this is the only feature you require, there is no need to upgrade.

Regarding security models, several publications are using Veins for security and privacy research, for example for [Privacy assessment in vehicular networks using simulation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/VTCFall.2014.6966211). However, due to the vast number of different approaches and lack of standard, no "default" security-centric models are likely to be included in Veins anytime soon.

Comment: *.manager.numVehicles = <any number>  . Does this work with Veins4a2 as well?

Comment: Yes it does. The .ned file documentation has additional explanations of how to use it.